# Is this a PHP preg_match bug or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: php, preg-match

I use the following regular expression to match valid domain names:
    `/^([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9]*-*[a-z0-9])*\.)+[a-z][a-z]+$/`
This works fine. But when I replace part of it with a domain name to match the domain name itself and sub domains of it, it doesn't work. For example, if I use
    `/^([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9]*-*[a-z0-9])*\.)*mycarbrokedown.be$/`
to match ns1.mycarbrokedown.be, preg_match returns 0.

I've used a couple online testers which confirm that my regular expression does match my string. Curiously, regextester.com doesn't return anything when I use the preg option.

All of this leads me to think that it's a bug in PHP. As I have no idea what's causing the bug, I haven't been able to find matching bug reports.

What's going on here?

Comment: Here's a link with some predefined regex patterns, including one for urls http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Answer (score 0):

Please try this regex and let me know of the results. It might be that you have whitespace or something else in front/the end of the string and that's the reason it doesn't match, so I removed ^ and &. Also this is a regex from RegexBuddy Library.

```
preg_match_all('/([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,}/i', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Comment: With $subject being ns1.mycarbrokedown.be, $matches had the value of 1 and $result had Array as its value.

I doubt whitespace is the problem as the input is being trimmed of it before testing.

Comment: the $matches value of 1 tells that it matched the pattern once, so it's a valid domain in $subject, if you need the individual parts then, knowing that it's a valid domain you can just do an `explode('.', $subject)` and extract the parts you need, if you need it to match a specific domain so you don't have to do another validation, then just add the domain like this `^([a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+mycarbrokedown\.net$` and if it matches for validity then just explode it and get the subdomains